# Full Image Background with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, background

I need to apply a plugin to an image when this one is loade via AJAX with jQuery .load method.

thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize that plugin in load success callback something like this..

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  // initialize  your plugin on image 
});
```